# how to invoke a variable in javascript with concatenation of two strings

Tags: javascript, asp.net

in my .aspx page I've got something like this-  I create dynamically javascript variables which look like this

```
var region11 = '' 
var region12 = ''
```

So when I click on a region of svg I get the id of the region which is for example `11` and I should set the href property  `region11` variable.
Unfortunately the javascript debbuger says that it cannot find `region` variable

```
  <% var regions = ICYGEN.MRF.Data.CityData.SelectProvinces(); %>
    <% foreach (ICYGEN.MRF.Data.Entities.Region region in regions)
       { %>

    var region<%= region.RegionID %> = '<%= MRFUrlHelper.Elections2015_RegionUrl(region.RegionID,region.Title, 1026) %>';
    <% } %>


    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        var svgMap = jQuery('#svg-map').contents().get(0);


        alert(region11);//it's Ok here and it finds it

        jQuery('svg path', svgMap).click(function () {
            var ids = String(this.id);
            location.href = region+ids; //can not find
```

Comment: When you look at the html source, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `region` instead of `region11` in your click event handler:

```
location.href = region+ids; //can not find
```

Change to:

```
location.href = region11+ids; //can not find
```

Or I suppose:

```
location.href = region<%= region.RegionID %>+ids; //can not find
```